# Not able to generate auto sum for a particular field in dynamically created rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in which I am generating rows dynamically. I had a field for which I need the value calculated automatically as I enter the values in other fields. The table structure in HTML is as below:

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 5px;" class="form_style_table" id="add_iaDetails_table">
                        <tr>                        
                            <td colspan="5" align="right" class="border_bottom_1">
                                <span class="float_left" id="status_msg"></span>
                                <input type="button" value="Add Detail" id="add_iaDetails_button" class="orange"/> 
                                <input type="button" value="Remove Checked" id="delete_iaDetails" class="orange"/>
                                <input type="button" value="Request Underpin" class="orange"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <th align="middle" valign="middle">Impact for</th>
                        <th align="middle" valign="middle">Rate</th>
                        <th align="middle" valign="middle">Days</th>
                        <th align="middle" valign="middle">Cost</th>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="30%"><select name="add_resource"></select></td>                  
                                <td><input type="text" id="rate" name="rate"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="days" name="days"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="cost" name="cost"/></td>
                                <td width="2%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="1"/></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
```

I am using the following code to generate rows:

```
$("#add_iaDetails_button").click(function () {
    $('#add_iaDetails_table').append('<tr><td width="30%"><select name="add_resource"></select></td><td><input type="text" id="rate" name="rate"/></td><td><input type="text" id="days" name="days"/></td><td><input type="text" id="cost" name="cost"/></td><td width="2%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="1"/></td></tr>'); });
```

Here I wanted cost calculated when I enter the values for rate and days.

I tried using .blur and .live, but was not working.

Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You appear to be duplicating ids across dynamically added rows... Id's must be unique on a page. Use classes instead to indicated which is `cost`, `days`, rate etc. To solve the event problem you need to use the deferred syntax of `on()` that takes a selector.

Comment: +1 for supplying code and HTML, but next time a JSFiddle will get faster results :) Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete answer below based on my earlier comments:

You need to use `class=""` or your existing `name=""` instead of ids for the input elements. I have gone with your existing `name=""` for now.

I have also used a script block for your template as putting HTML in a string constant is a maintenance nightmare e.g.

```
$("#add_iaDetails_button").click(function () {
    $('#add_iaDetails_table').append($('#template').html());
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QLQJf/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '[name=rate], [name=days]', function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $rate = $row.find('input[name=rate]');
        var $days = $row.find('input[name=days]');
        var $cost = $row.find('input[name=cost]');
        var rate = parseFloat($rate.val());
        var days = parseFloat($days.val());
        $cost.val(rate * days);
    });
});
```

basically it waits for any change on either the days or rate and finds the matching fields relative to a parent row. The code can be simplified, but I went for most readable this time.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to change the `id`s inside your html (`rate`, `days`, `cost`) to classes because duplicate id are not valid.

```
<tr>
    <td width="30%"><select name="add_resource"></select></td>                  
    <td><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="days" name="days"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="cost" name="cost"/></td>
    <td width="2%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="1"/></td>
</tr>
```

and

```
$('#add_iaDetails_table').append('<tr><td width="30%"><select name="add_resource"></select></td><td><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate"/></td><td><input type="text" class="days" name="days"/></td><td><input type="text" class="cost" name="cost"/></td><td width="2%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="1"/></td></tr>'); });
```

Then try this for handling the events

```
$('#add_iaDetails_table').on('change', '.rate, .days', function(){
  // do the calculations in here..
});
```

This way we delegate the event handling to the table so that it works with dynamically added elements as well..

Comment: Thanks a lot,thats working good but only for the first row.....am working on to add row numbers

Comment: you will have to provide us with the code that does the calculation to see what goes wrong..